Unwanted spaced in format string when running Python code in snakemake
I have a project that was running fine until I had to update the conda environment. Suddenly, certain strings got extra spaces around variables that are inserted in the string with f"...".
Consider this:
foo = "bar"
print(f"foo is now:{foo}.")

The correct output (the one I am getting with the previous conda environment) is foo is now:bar.. In the new environment, however, I get foo is now: bar ..
The previous environment had python version 3.10.9 and snakemake version 7.19.1. The new environment has python version 3.12.3 and snakemake version 7.19.1.
Here is a minimal snakefile that showcases this behavior (at least in my environment):
rule all:
  run:
    foo = "bar"
    print(f"foo is now:{foo}.")


https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/2480
